# Vectors : Line of intersection no Z axis component?

Tags: vectors

I've been doing and exposing to many vectors questions, mostly from Singapore-Cambridge A level questions,  and finding line of intersection between $2$ or $3$ planes, always yield line of intersections with equation that comprises of position vector with $(0)$ at the $z\text{_ axis}$, e.g. $(5 , 3 , 0)$ , and the direction vector always yield a $(1)$ for the direction along $z\text{_ axis}$, e.g. $(2,2,1) $
Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed define a line as follows:
$$\vec{x}=\vec{p}+t\vec{d}$$
where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{p}$ is a "position" and $\vec{d}$ a "direction". However, this expression is not unique, the following expression determines the same line:
$$\vec{x}=(\vec{p}+t_0\vec{d})+(t-t_0)\vec{d}$$
for any $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Now $(\vec{p}+t_0\vec{d})$ is the "position".

Similarly, the same line is still given by 
$$\vec{x}=\vec{p}+t\frac{\vec{d}}{k}$$
for any $k\in \mathbb{R}$ (not $0$).

Thus, if your line is not perpendicular to the $z$ axis, your direction vector can always be scaled to have a component 1 along the z axis, and your position vector can be shifted to have component 0 along the z axis.

Comment: What is the implication when the position vector of a line is e.g.( 5,5,1) , the direction vector is e.g.(4,2,0) ? Is it that the z axis component is always z=1 ?  What is the implication when the line is perpendicular to z axis? What is the implication when a line is parallel to the z axis?is it z component of direction vector=0?  Sorry for my ignorance! I hope i can learn from all of you !

Comment: Lines with direction vector $(4,2,0)$ are perpendicular to the z axis. No matter what you multiply this with, you cannot rescale it to have z component 1. A line perpendicular to the z axis has 0 for the z component of the direction vector. A line parallel to the z axis has 0 for the x and y component of the direction vector.

Comment: Ok, but there will be a point of intersection with z axis right , so probably a point with e.g. (x,y, 1) ?

Comment: Then, is it possible to have a direction vector e.g. (9,9,1) and position vector e.g. (5,5,0)? Because i was thinking, if there is a z axis component, surely there should be a position vector with a z axis component, so how is (5,5,0) possible? But then again, there are infinite points that can lie on a line, so a point having position vector=0 of the z axis component  is possible with a direction vector with a z axis component, is it?

Comment: Intersections with the z axis would be points of the form (0,0,z).

Yes, it is possible to have direction (9,9,1) and position (5,5,0). The only restriction is that the direction vector should not be (0,0,0).

Comment: If a line is perpendicular to z axis, wouldn't it be parallel to y axis, and perpendicular to x axis? I used my thumb, index and middle finger to form x ,y , z axis, to visualise

Comment: Whats the implication of both z component of direction and position vector is zero? The line is perpendicular to z axis, is it a line parallel to y axis? Or not necessarily?

Comment: The line with direction vector with z axis component =0 , is perpendicular to z axis. This line , only cuts the z axis at one point , correct? So the z component of position vector, could be e.g. 0, 1, or 2 , etc?

Comment: A line perpendicular to the z axis is simply a line that makes a 90 degree angle with the z axis. Both the x axis and the y axis are perpendicular to the z axis. The x axis can be described by position (0,0,0) and direction (1,0,0). The y axis can be described by position (0,0,0) and direction (0,1,0). Both are perpendicular to the z axis, only one of them is parallel to the y axis.